# unscope only the order statements

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

How can i unscope all the `ORDER BY` sql statemnts in rails 3?

```
chain.unscoped.order("id ASC")
```

problem that i have is that this will also drop the WHERE statements and my query is meaningless without them. something like `.unscoped('order')` would be nice.

Comment: Mmm could you please enlighten/elaborate why you would want to "unscope" the order? Should it not exactly be the result of all the `where`'s that should be ordered?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `except()` method.

```
chain.except(:order)
```

I think that'll do what you want.

Comment: Since Rails 4 you can use `chain.unscope(:order)`